# In-memory Angular Post to Backend

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, in-memory

[image]
[image]
So i have 2 components 1 is form and the other is dialog with form, so when i click the dialog with form and input a data i want to save it first in `in-memory` then when i save it i want all my input in dialog with form will post it to the backend? how to achieved that?

here is what i did when saving the form in the `in-memory`(i call the generate url which is - 'api/users')

```
save(){
this.http.post(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'users', this.serialForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
console.log(res)
})
```

heres what my in-memory looks like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const users = [ 
      { id: 11, itemCode: 'ICT000000211', qtyReceived:0, inputs:[{
        deliveryId: 0,
        serialNum:'string'
      }] },
    ];
    console.log(users)
    return { users : users };
  }
}
```

after i saved i want to post it all my `in-memory` to my real backend which is this code

```
PostAll(){
return this.http.post(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'RealBackEnd/PostItem', data)
}
```

Comment: How you backend is accepting data.and in memory when you want to send any time when you open or when you close the dialog box at that time only.

Comment: DialogBox with Form component - when i click the button save my input will post it in the `in-memory data` and close it. 
form component- there will be a button will including the posting of my inmemory data and the data in my form 

this is what i wanted to achieved but how

Answer (score 1):

Make one general service where you will be holding the data in array.

Now when you open dialog and fill that form also and on click of save pass current form value. to you main service.

assume that in memory data you have an array of data for users:

users:any[]

in above object you have all in memory data so now when you save do following.

```html
PostAll(){
users.foreach(element=>{
 this.http.post(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'RealBackEnd/PostItem', element)
}
}
```

Like above you can do.

```html
save(){
//global variable
users.push(this.serialForm.value)
this.http.post(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'users', this.serialForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
console.log(res)
})
```

this way you can achieve

Comment: trying this, but not working.

Comment: what issue you are getting

Comment: let me construct again the question, so here's i wanted to achieved. i want to get what i input in `in-memory`  which in the image so i can send it to the back end based on i upload i have to components dialog and the other component which is the main so i want to get what i input in dialog and send it to the main so i can post in the web api